# How can i pass imports in Python higher up the hierarchy?

Tags: python, import, global-variables, wrapper, helper

I am developping a program which runs on two different plattforms. Depending on which plattform I want to run it, the import directories and the names of the libraries change. For this reason i set a variable called RUN_ON_PC to True or False.

I want to implement a helper which sets the paths correctly and imports the libraries with the correct name depending of the platform and gives an interface with the same name of the libraries to the main program. The module myimporthelper is either in the "/mylib" or in the "/sd/mylib" directory. The other module names in these directories differ.

I try to do the following which is not working, since the imported modules from myimporthelper.py are not visible to main.py:

main.py:

```
RUN_ON_PC = True
import sys
if RUN_ON_PC:
    sys.path.append("/mylib1")
else:
    sys.path.append("/sd/mylib1")
import myimporthelper
myimporthelper.importall(RUN_ON_PC)

a = moduleA.ClassA()       -> produces NameError: name not defined
```

myimporthelper.py:

```
import sys
def importall(run_on_pc):
    if (run_on_pc == True):
        sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\.....\\mylib")
        import module1 as moduleA
    else:
        sys.path.append("/sd/mylib")
        import module_a as moduleA
```

I want to keep the main.py short and want to outsource the platform dependent importing stuff to other module. I was not able to find a solution for this and would aprecciate any help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to qualify the name with the helper module name

```
a = myimporthelper.moduleA.ClassA()
```

But the `moduleA` name has to be accessible. If you import it inside a function in the helper it won't be, because of scope, unless you assign it to a name you previously declared as `global` in the helper module function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this way i was able to solve the problem. It seems that it was too late yesterday for programming.